# SimpleDateFormat not recognized by NetBeans

Tags: simpledateformat

I am trying to retrieve a value from a javascript variable, which calculates the elapsed time of an embedded audio file. In the servlet page, my attempt at extracting the time using the following:

```
String x=(String)req.getParameter("h1"); //h1 is the hidden field associated with the form containing the audio file.
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date etime = parser.parse(x);
```

shows an error at the IDE, stating: 
 "**cannot find symbol: class SimpleDateFormat**"

Since, SimpleDateFormat is a class of java.text.DateFormat, which belongs to java.lang.Object, I considered to be implicitly imported.

Kindly help. 
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Only classes in `java.lang` are implicitly imported.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html)  This includes things such as `Math` and `String`.  *Everything else* must be explicitly imported.

Furthermore, `java.lang` is a different package (read: subfolder) than `java.text`.  There's no way that one implies the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just import: `import java.text.*;`